# Auditing SQL Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

As I understand it, the Security eventlog cannot be copied to WAD Diagnostics storage and SQL Server auditing is not available for SQL Azure.

What solutions have you come up with for auditing access to a SQL Azure database?

At a minimum it should be login, IP and when; but preferably the actual SQL executed as well.

Comment: If you enforce data access through stored procedures, you could certainly log every time a stored procedure is called with the details. This is cumbersome, of course, and doesn't include the actual login event (which is just a pre-cursor to the code being executed, but still).

Comment: @AaronBertrand We are using Entity Framework - so no sprocs to add auditing to. I guess the sledge hammer approach would be to add triggers to all of the tables which write an audit table - but that is even more cumbersome!

Comment: There is also no such thing as a select trigger, so good luck there. Can Entity Framework not call stored procedures?

Comment: It can (although I think the new DBContext stuff may not be able to yet), but one of the points of using an ORM is so that you don't have to! :)

Comment: I'm not sure why the EF crowd thinks stored procedures are such a huge burden and riddled with downsides.

Comment: There are pros and cons, but the ability to write a LINQ query in C# is very productive - and not having to write any CUD sprocs at all is just a lot less effort. Of course this is likely to make a DBA a bit nervous!

Comment: @JasonSteele Having DB code outside of the DB is problematic for a lot of reasons...

Comment: Yeah since most of the LINQ questions here are "how do I make LINQ form this nice query that is so easy to do in T-SQL?" or "how do I optimize this thing that LINQ did for me behind the scenes?" Getting there fastest is not always best. :-)

Comment: This is a philosophical debate that could go on forever and is also getting a bit off topic so I think we should leave it there.

Answer (score 1):

Recently the Azure SQL team introduced some new system views that expose at least the login infos.

Announcing: New System Views for Windows Azure SQL Database:
http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2012/11/05/announcing-new-system-views-for-windows-azure-sql-database/